# Работа с коллекциями java. Первый элемент не считывается

Tags: java, коллекции

Учусь работать с коллекциями на конкретном задании: Анализатор текста. 
Вроде бы хорошо всё идёт, но вот не могу найти решение проблемы заголовке.

Сам код:

```
public class Parser {

Path file = Paths.get("src\\main\\resources\\text.txt");
Path fileExcuses = Paths.get("src\\main\\resources\\excuses.txt");



public void parseLine() throws IOException {

    ArrayList<String> lines = (ArrayList<String>) Files.readAllLines(file, Charset.defaultCharset());
    ArrayList<String> excuses = (ArrayList<String>) Files.readAllLines(fileExcuses, Charset.defaultCharset());
    ArrayList<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> excusesList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String line : lines) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " \t\n\r,.");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            wordsList.add(st.nextToken());
        }
    }

    for (String line : excuses) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " \t\n\r,.");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            excusesList.add(st.nextToken());
        }
    }

    HashMap<String, Integer> repeats = new HashMap<>();
    Integer count;
    for (String i : wordsList) {
        if(Collections.frequency(excusesList, i) == 1)
        continue;
        count = repeats.get(i);
        repeats.put(i, count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(excusesList);
    System.out.println(repeats);
  }
}
```

Работа программы:

Считываем файл с текстом и заносим его по словам в `ArrayList`, затем делаем статистику сколько раз встречались слова в тексте.

Второй `ArrayList` - предлоги, местоимения на русском и английском языке, которые были в тексте и не должны учитываться в статистике.

Вот пример файла с текстом:
**garry potter garry garry potter**

Выход в консоли:

> {garry=2, garry=1, potter=2}

Вы уже заметили проблему. Первое слово из текста всегда будет вынесено отдельно в статистику, даже если оно встречалось больше одного раза.

Что нужно изменить, чтобы первое слово не было отдельно в статистике?

p.s. также, буду рад советам по коду и в целом по программе! Спасибо за внимание!

файл с предлогами - http://dropmefiles.com/YBssT
исходный текст - http://dropmefiles.com/zsZtu

Comment: что в файле excuses? Я запустил ваш пример с текстом `garry potter garry garry potter` и получил: `{garry=3, potter=2}`

Comment: 90% предлогов английского и русского языка, не включая составных, даже если я не буду учитывать их, то всё равно будет выводить с ошибкой. Как у вас это вышло?))

Comment: **{garry=1}---
{garry=1, potter=1}---
{garry=1, garry=1, potter=1}---
{garry=2, garry=1, potter=1}---
{garry=2, garry=1, potter=2}---
{garry=2, garry=1, potter=2}** ---Вот из консоли, как заполняется коллекция

Comment: а в тесте точно нет несоответствия по символам? Попробуйте руками с консоли вбить текст и его распотрошить

Comment: нет, проверял) 
где-то счётчик сбился, но где - не знаю)
спасибо за совет! буду пытаться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем файле на 1й позиции есть невидимый символ `U+FEFF`([ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm)). Чтобы его увидеть можете вывести посимвольно вашу строку из файла или посмотреть тут - [Unicode character inspector](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%EF%BB%BFgarry%20potter%20garry%20garry%20potter).
Поэтому в результатах `garry` повторяется 2 раза - 1 раз с этим символом и 2 без него.

**PS:** вы можете посчитать количество вхождений с помощью Stream API:

```
Map<String, Long> repeats = wordsList.parallelStream()
        .filter(s -> !excusesList.contains(s))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: identity() это что?

Comment: функция, которая возвращает входной аргумент - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--

Comment: самое интересное, что если провести тот же тест, с гарри, то результат абсолютно тот же)) Ваш способ, конечно лучше

Comment: мне кажется проблема во входных данных - дайте свои входные файлы (можете залить и скинуть ссылку)

Comment: обновил пост)))

Comment: какая у вас кодировка? половина символов - кракозябры

Comment: выяснил - iso-8859-1. Дайте также входной файл - скорее всего проблема в нем

Comment: utf-8 ставил во входных файлах, т.к. на винде создаётся автоматом в ansi и после этого вылазит ошибка, мол не считывается формат файла. Все символы нормально отображаются.  Ок, сейчас обновлю и скину text.txt

Comment: вы какой-то другой текст выложили. С ним какие проблемы? Я хочу посмотреть ваш текст с `garry`, чтобы повторить вашу проблему.

Comment: аа, так без разницы какой текст, ок, сейчас

Comment: я изменил файл, загрузил свой с гарии, проверьте пожалуйста))

Comment: нашел проблему - дополнил ответ

Comment: А как его убрать?)

Comment: удалите и напишите 1е слово заново. я даже не знаю как вы смогли его поставить...